# Session Variables Not Carrying Over to Other Pages

Tags: php, session

My first page is:

```
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION['test'] = 'testSession';

?>
```

Other page is:

```
<?php

session_start();

echo $_SESSION['test'];

?>
```

There is no output on the second page. The error log outputs:

[30-Oct-2013 12:13:53] PHP Warning:  session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent

Are there any ideas as to what the problem might be? The session variables can be outputted fine on the first page (when I tested), but not on the second. Thank you.

Comment: Is this the 1st code at the top of your page? Do you have a space, or line return before your opening php tag - `_<?php`

Comment: One more thing - You should pass SSID somehow to that another page. GET. POST. COOKIES...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using sessions in your application then you must start the session at the very top of your page, you must avoid spaces or extra line spaces after

```
<?php
```

and

```
session_start();
```

Write your code as follows:

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['test'] = 'testSession';

?>
```

and on second page,

```
<?php
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['test'];

?>
```

Hope this solves the problem, and if still not then you may use following technique:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

$_SESSION['test'] = 'testSession';

?>
```

and on second page,

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['test'];

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to ask what is the `ob_start();`?